# Accept-ranges set to none on doing range request on twilio mp3 recording url

Tags: html, audio, twilio

I have been using twilio services to recording calls. 
I want to perform range request on the recording url.

I am using the plain html audio tag.

It is working with the format .wav

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Recordings/REXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.wav. I am getting response like this with header accept-ranges: bytes

[image]

but when I tried with .mp3 it does not work https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Recordings/REXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mp3
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid we don't support range requests on mp3 files as the files are converted on the fly.

Comment: is there any way to achive it. I can use wav file. But the html player I am using supports only mp3. Any workaround on that ?

Comment: You could download the file and build your own range requests on it yourself? We just don't support it I'm afraid.